# How can I use double pointers correctly in this case?

Tags: c, pointers

I am doing a boarding queue and I am using a simple bubble sort algorithm to sort the queue I have, I am using 2 pointers to store the values I am comparing and 2 double pointer to modify the value inside each node that I want to swap. My problem is when I want to change where my double pointers are pointing in order to iterate through all the queue, it never compiles, I have tried:

this:`**r = &(r->next)`,

this: `**r = &(*r->next)`,

or this: `**r = &(**r->next)`

Same happens when I try to change where my double pointer "a" is pointing. This is the full method just in case you need to see it,

```
int sortBoardingQueue(BoardingQueue *qPtr){
    int size = calculateSize(qPtr);

    Passenger *t = qPtr->head;
    Passenger *a = qPtr->head->next;
    Passenger **r = &(qPtr->head);
    Passenger **q = &(qPtr->next);
    for (int i = size-1; i <=0; i--)
    {
        while(t != NULL){
            if (t->seatNumber>a->seatNumber)
            {
                **r = *a;
                **q = *t;
            }
            t = t->next;
            a = a->next;
            **r = &(r->next);
            **a = &(a->next);
        }
    }

}

//the declarations of the structs I am using in my header file
typedef struct boardingQueue {
    Passenger* head; // points to the Passenger at the front/head of the queue
    Passenger* tail; // points to the Passenger at the end/tail of the queue
} BoardingQueue;

typedef struct passenger {
char name[30];          // the passenger's name
double passportNumber;  // their passport number
int seatNumber;         // their seat number on the plane
struct passenger* next; // a pointer to the next passenger in the queue after this one
} Passenger;
```

Comment: @Andrés Álvarez Show the definition of Passenger.

Comment: `a` is not a double-pointer, and `**r` is a `Passenger`, not a pointer. If you want to change where `r` is pointing, assign a new value to `r`. Don't insert ampersands and asterisks willy-nilly trying to stumble across the correct code (it most likely won't be, even if it compiles).

Comment: It is C language:

Comment: Edit: the struct passenger is already in the code

Comment: struct boardingQueue should contain "next" for initializing of q (Passenger **q = &(qPtr->next);)

Answer (score 0):

If the pointer `r` is declared and initialized like this

```
Passenger **r = &(qPtr->head);
```

then in this statement

```
**r = &(r->next);
```

`**r` has the type `Passenger`. Moreover r is pointing to a pointer. S this expression `r->next` is incorrect because pointers do not have the data member next (pointers are not structures).

So all three expressions

```
**r = &(r->next),

**r = &(*r->next),

**r = &(**r->next)
```

are incorrect. For example the expression

```
&(**r->next)
```

is equivalent to

```
&(** ( r->next ) )
```

It seems what you mean is the following

```
r = &( *r )->next;
```

Take into account that this declaration

```
Passenger **q = &(qPtr->next);
```

is also invalid because the structure `BoardingQueue` does not have the data member `next`.

also the condition in the for loop

```
for (int i = size-1; i <=0; i--)
```

is invalid. It will be valid only in the case when `size` is less than or equal to 1.:)

You have to rewrite the function `sortBoardingQueue` anew at least using valid C expressions. After that you can ask a question: why does not my sort function work.:)

Answer (score 0):

-- next time it will be easier to get an answer if the posted code snippet is exactly what you're feeding into the compiler, and if you include your compiler errors *exactly as they appear* with your question.

I restructured your example code + added a main function to show some of the compiler errors to show what I mean:

---

## Code example

```
#define NULL 0
//the declarations of the structs I am using in my header file
typedef struct passenger {
char name[30];          // the passenger's name
double passportNumber;  // their passport number
int seatNumber;         // their seat number on the plane
struct passenger* next; // a pointer to the next passenger in the queue after this one
} Passenger;

typedef struct boardingQueue {
    Passenger* head; // points to the Passenger at the front/head of the queue
    Passenger* tail; // points to the Passenger at the end/tail of the queue
} BoardingQueue;

int sortBoardingQueue(BoardingQueue *qPtr){
    int size = 3; // func undefined?? calculateSize(qPtr);

    Passenger *t = qPtr->head;
    Passenger *a = qPtr->head->next;
    Passenger **r = &(qPtr->head);
    Passenger **q = &(qPtr->next);
    for (int i = size-1; i <=0; i--)
    {   
        while(t != NULL){
            if (t->seatNumber>a->seatNumber)
            {
                **r = *a; 
                **q = *t; 
            }
            t = t->next;
            a = a->next;
            **r = &(r->next);
            **a = &(a->next);
        }
    }   

}

int main(){
    // make passengers
    Passenger a = {"p1", 111.0, 1, NULL};
    Passenger b = {"p2", 222.0, 2, NULL};
    Passenger c = {"p2", 222.0, 3, NULL};

    // make boarding queue a->c->b
    a.next = &c; 
    c.next = &b; 
    BoardingQueue q = {&a, &b};

    sortBoardingQueue(&q);
}
```

---

## Compiler errors

dp.c: In function ‘sortBoardingQueue’: dp.c:22:27: error:
 ‘BoardingQueue {aka struct boardingQueue}’ has no member named ‘next’
      `Passenger **q = &(qPtr->next);`

From this one, its because boardingQueue has no member `next`, only `head` and `tail`. (Maybe you wanted that to point to a passenger? I can't tell what you intended from context)

```
dp.c:33:22: error: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union
              `**r = &(r->next);`
```

For this one, r is of type `Passenger **`, so it points to a passenger struct. If you really want to access that struct's next field, you'll have to use `(*r)->next`

```
  dp.c:34:13: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have
 ‘Passenger {aka struct passenger}’)
              **a = &(a->next);
```

For this one, `a` is a single pointer. You can only dereference it once.

---

So, I hope that helps you plenty for this assignment! And next time, if you post a minimum, reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example you're bound to get better answers faster.